# My PhD thesis does not include a Literature Review chapter

Tags: phd, literature-review

I am due to submit my PhD in a week and I am starting to panic over not having a dedicated chapter with a literature review. My topic covers different fields of study so I have added some literature review within the content of every chapter when that field is explored. Now I am worried because my thesis does not follow the standard structure. 
Do you think it will help to make this clear in the Introduction?

Comment: 2 years later: How did it turn out?

Answer (score 3):

This is a question for your advisor. What will s/he accept in your dissertation? If it is a acceptable to the advisor (and any committee) then there is no issue at all.

It seems pretty clear from what you write that you *have*, in fact, reviewed the literature, rather than just ignoring it. How you present your findings is, in a sense, just a matter of writing style. If it works, it works.

But your advisor may have veto power here, so make sure they are happy.